# clip circle array but keep whole circles only

Tags: tikz-pgf

My code below generate some partial circles. how can I do a clip but discard the partial circles?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \clip (0,0) circle (1.8cm);
    \foreach \i in {-2,-1.5,...,2} {
        \foreach \j in {-2,-1.5,...,2} {
            \draw (\i,\j) circle (0.2cm);
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current output:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    %\clip (0,0) circle (1.8cm);
    \foreach \i in {-2,-1.5,...,2} {
        \foreach \j in {-2,-1.5,...,2} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\distA{sqrt(max((\i+0.2)^2,(\i-0.2)^2)+max((\j+0.2)^2,(\j-0.2)^2)}
        \ifdim\distA cm<2cm
            \draw (\i,\j) circle (0.2cm);
        \fi
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea is that the maximum distance from the point `(0,0)` of the inner circles, has to be less than 2cm. But this way you don't have to clip at all.

[image]